# Does being overly attentive to hygiene impair your immune system?

Tags: immune-system, influenza, obsessive-compulsive

Like a lot of Japanese girls, I'm a bit obsessed with personal hygiene. Sometimes I get up 2AM to have a shower... after already having one before going to sleep, because something just doesn't feel "right".

And I work in a more diverse corporate environment where we have people coming and going from Korea and Hong Kong all the time. One thing I notice is that I catch flu quite easily, at almost every single turn of a season. Just recently I caught flu twice... within half a month, both recovered well within 3 days with minor complications remained like running nose or cough.

At the same time, I notice that colleagues and ex-college friends who are about the same height, age and weight as me but doesn't pay much attention to personal hygiene rarely get sick...

I understand the whole thing could just be a confirmation bias. But I still want to know, is there any scientific studies done which shows that being super "clean" actually "spoil" or "overly-pamper" your immune system?

Comment: I doubt there is any relation at all between personal hygiene and flu or immune system. Hygiene can only keep the body clean from the outside, but not protect it if you're around sick people who can transfer bacteria e.g. by sneezing.

Comment: There are a large number of assumptions here that could be incorrect. But getting up at 2 am for another shower sounds abnormal.